# How can I replace raw query to laravel format

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```
DB::select("SELECT products.* ,categories.* FROM products 
INNER JOIN category_products ON category_products.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN categories ON category_products.category_id = categories.id 
WHERE categories.slug='$slug'")
```

This row query working fine but I can not access their relation like

> $product->Categories->first()->name
>
> @foreach($product->Images as $image)

My product Model below :

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function Category(){
        return $this->hasMany(CategoryProduct::class);
    }
    public function getCategory($id){
       return Category::find($id)->name;
    }
    public function Images(){
       return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }

    public function Categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class, 'category_products');
    }
}
```

so how can convert my code to Laravel eloquent

Comment: "so how can convert my code to Laravel eloquent"  https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins

Comment: Please check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52330836/5013099

Answer (score 3):

Please check this documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations

**According to documentation, you can change your code like this:**

```
$products= Product::whereHas('Categories', function($q) use ($slug)
{
    $q->where('slug', $slug);

})->get();
```